# Compare data from a string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare

I'm trying to compare something that i read with fgets with the words from the first column of the array, but I can't get it, I thing it could be the `\0` at the end of each string but I can't get the comparison works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRLEN 3  

const char *bdato [][columns]={
    {"tc","Torta Cubana"},
    {"th","Torta Huatulco"},
    {"tm","Torta Mexicana"},
    {"tr","Torta Rusa"},
    {"r", "Refresco"},
    {"a", "Agua sabor"}};

int total() {
    char v[20];
    int flag=0,cont=0;
    fgets(v,sizeof(v),stdin);
    do {
        if(strcmp(v,bdato[cont][0])==0){ /*this*/
            flag=1;
            printf("I found one");
        }
        cont++;
    } while(!(flag==1||cont==5));
}
```

the rewritten code:

```
  #defines .....
  .............
  .............
 int total(){
 size_t len = strlen(v);
        printf("something here");
        fgets(v,sizeof(v),stdin);
        len = strlen(v);
        if(len>0){
        v[len - 1] = '\0';}
        if(strcmp((v,bdato[cont][0])==0)){
            /*another code*/
        }
 }
```

Comment: `fgets` includes a newline.  Also, you appear to have an extra closing brace.

Comment: yeah, I didn't remember that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string comparisons are failing because `fgets()` includes the newline that ends the input line.

You need to strip that out, something like

```
const size_t len = strlen(v);
if(len > 0)
  v[len - 1] = '\0';
```

should do it. The `if` is just to be somewhat sure we're not about to index backwards.

Also, you should check that `fgets()` succeeds before relying on `v` to have valid input.

Comment: @user2461687: Consider two cases: __Case 1:__ There was no newline at the end of the line. __Case 2:__ There was no input at all.

Comment: @Bill Lynch: you are correct for case 1. For case 2, `fgets()` will return `NULL` and `v` is untouched, so anything can happen.  `fgets()` return value should definitely be checked.

Comment: I was at the school,mmm I don't know how to implement this into my code

Comment: I had to remove the const declaration because this is always reading, the if decision is between a loop

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `sh` to compile your `c` program (most of us do that for such small samples i guess) a good thing to learn is to use the program `cat`  with the option `-e` , let's take a look at your program. For the sake of the example i added a printf() in your do while like so :

```
print("%s",v); //note that they are no \n
```

Let's now look at the output if i enter Torta Cubana for example :

```
Torta Cubana$
```

The $ (thanks to `cat -e`) does tell us one thing, you got a `\n` in your string `v`.
And that's why your strcmp() is failing, since your array bdato doesnt have `\n` inside your strings.

You have two choices here, the first and the most **clean** way, is to remove the `\n` from `v` (And for this case the answer from unwind is well-fitting).

The second, way uglier is to change your `bdato` to this :

```
const char *bdato [][columns]={
    {"tc","Torta Cubana\n"},
    {"th","Torta Huatulco\n"},
    {"tm","Torta Mexicana\n"},
    {"tr","Torta Rusa\n"},
    {"r", "Refresco\n"},
    {"a", "Agua sabor\n"}
};
```

But you would not do *that*, would you ?

Comment: I made something like that but I knew it was not a good way to do it, so how it should be the code for the comparison

Comment: @user2461687 look at  unwind's  answer for doing the clean way, my answer was more about using cat to detect thoses behaviours and how to act thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `'\n'` at the end of the `v` array before comparing:

```
if (!fgets(v,sizeof(v),stdin))
    return -1;
v[strcspn(v, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: Sorry for trying to be creative.  The beauty of using `strcspn()` is that it works in all cases, including when there is a missing `'\n'` at the end of file.

Comment: That's a pretty nice way of going about it actually. I misunderstood the return value of `strcspn`. (I just assumed it was going to return -1 or something like that if the `'\n'` wasn't found.)

Comment: Learn something new everyday... I started C in 1980, still learning too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest & cleaner approach is as **@unwind** had suggested. But even in that approach I always prefer to use the safer `strncmp()` than `strcmp()`. This is particularly useful in such scenarios as you facing.

Applying `strncmp()` approach here & if you knew that `fgets()` appends a newline character, then the changes required in your code are from:

```
if(strcmp(v,bdato[cont][0])==0){ /*this*/
```

to

```
if ((strlen(v) == strlen(bdato[cont][0])) && (strncmp(v,bdato[cont][0],strlen(v))==0)){ /*this*/
```

the "-1" after `strlen(v)` is to ignore the newline character.

Comment: Not a good approach: if the user enters "t", `strncmp()` will erroneously match 4 entries, and an empty string, all 6!

Comment: @chqrlie: True! I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @chqrlie: Just rectified my solution. I hope this works! Do tell.

Comment: What exactly are you gaining with this convoluted alternative to `strcmp` that happens to be exactly equivalent?

Comment: @chqrlie: Isn't it recommended to use the 'n' functions (like strncpy, strncmp, ...) when possible?

Comment: No, it is not.  `strncpy` must be avoided always. Very few programmers know what it really does, and even fewer need it.  don't use that one. For the others, `strncmp()`, `strncat()`... they may be useful in comes circumstances, but not here.

Comment: @chqrlie: Hmm.. Yeah, makes sense. Thanks.

Is this still a downvote? ;-)

Comment: I personally use a different approach: I have a utility function `int strstart(const char *str, const char *prefix, char **endp);` that checks if `str` starts with the string `prefix` and returns 1 and sets `*endp` to the character after the prefix.  I would then use this code: `if (strstart(v,bdato[cont][0],&p) && is_separator(*p))`

Comment: I'm trying to understand this :/